# How can I get rgb frame from h264 stream, with gstreamer sdk 1.5 for iOS?

Tags: ios8, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have gstreamer on linux which streams RTP h264 video stream

I have iOS app which need to receive the RGB frames and pass them to video conference sdk.

I know gstreamer 1.5 is decoding with VideoToolBox, thats why I wanna use it

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a capsfilter for the source of your h264 decoder:

gst-launch stream ! h264parse ! h264_decoder ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! sink_to_location(needs RGB support as well to avoid negotiation problems)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thnx but need to use RTP h264 encoded stream. what i want to do is to use the gstreamer sdk for iOS. i wanna use to handle the rtp stream and decode the frames by hardware acceleration. i dont know how to use the iOS sdk for such a case